# Can one cancel the return flight with Qatar Airways and if so, what is the fee?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, fees-and-charges, qatar-airways, return-tickets

https://www.qatarairways.com/en/travel-with-confidence.html ([mirror](https://archive.vn/mOYCp)) states:

> [Applicable for tickets issued up to 30 April 2021.] You also have the option to refund the unutilised value of your ticket to the original form of payment with no penalties or refund fees.

Assume a passenger purchase a round-trip ticket with Qatar Airways before 30 April 2021. Can the passenger cancel the return flight with Qatar Airways and if so, what is the fee if any?

I'm interested to know when the return flight is canceled before the passenger took the departure flight, as well as when the return flight is canceled after.

Comment: Mostly it is the question: "How much cheaper or more expensive is the one way ticket?" And the answer to that question: "The one way ticket is more expensive than the return." Resulting in you having to pay more in case of a partial cancelation.

Answer (score 2):

The terms and conditions are pretty sparse and are not entirely conclusive. See https://www.qatarairways.com/en/travel-with-confidence.html#terms I'm sure there is a more detailed document, but can't find it.

> Can the passenger cancel the return flight with Qatar Airways and if so, what is the fee if any?

You can cancel the return flight. That would qualify as a change, not a cancellation. There is no change fee, but Qatar would reprise the itinerary as a one way and calculate the fare difference. If the one-way price is cheaper, you can get a refund on the difference. If it's more expensive you actually have to pay additional money.

> ... when the return flight is canceled after (departure).

That's less clear. I don't see anything in the T&C that covers this case specifically.

However, in my experience (pre-covid, different airlines), this typically triggers a change fee but NOT a reprising of the itinerary. Hence doing a change or cancellation after departure has been significantly cheaper (and also recommended by friendly airline agents to me).

Comment: Thanks for the information, very interesting that canceling the return trip after departure can be cheaper!